# class func, what does this mean in Xcode and why does self change from myClass to myClass.Type within it

Tags: xcode, swift

apple has some sample code called adventure found here:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Adventure-Swift/Introduction/Intro.html

in the function inferCharacterType they use Character.Type to determine the which subclass of character is used. what is .Type . I option click it and it is not defined and without documentation. The classes passed to inferCharacterType are inherit from the character class. Does .Type indicate the identity of a specific type of character(one of the classes that inherits from character)

```
// This function uses pattern matching to infer the appropriate enum value based on the type provided.
func inferCharacterType(fromType: Character.Type) -> CharacterType {
    switch fromType {
        case is Goblin.Type:
            return CharacterType.Goblin
        case is Cave.Type:
            return CharacterType.Cave
        case is Boss.Type:
            return CharacterType.Boss
        case is Warrior.Type:
            return CharacterType.Warrior
        case is Archer.Type:
            return CharacterType.Archer
        default:
            fatalError("Unknown type provided for \(__FUNCTION__).")
    }
}
```

so i did some experimentation and intentionally cause an error to determine the identity of self. I found that only "class func" shows myClass.Type as self and "func" shows myClass

here are the pictures

func types
[image: class func]

the next picture

[image: rugular]

I would like a reference to where this information can be looked up. Thanks Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods preceded with `class` or `static` are "type methods". You can find out more from the Swift Programming Language book, in the [section on type methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID241).

Type methods are methods that are called on a type itself, rather than on an instance of that type.

```
let object = MyClass()
object.doSomething()       // instance method
MyClass.doSomethingElse()  // type method
```

As such, instead of `self` refering to the receiving instance (as with instance methods), it refers to the type itself when used inside a type method.

`.Type` itself refers to the [metatype type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455), that is to say, the type of the type.